# how to get the unique item from array ignore string encode in php?

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

By using array_unique() I want to get unique German words from $vocaulary. 
but some of the item encoded in utf-8, and some encoded in ASCII,
I tried using utf8_encode() to force them encode to utf-8, but not work.
in this array, "Handelsbilanz" is not unique, but when I print it out, they are same strings.
[file is here.](http://goo.gl/XE8lNN)

`$volcabulary =array (
      0 => 'Handelsfreiheit',
      1 => 'Handel (Händler)',
      2 => 'Handel, auswärtiger',
      3 => 'Handelsbilanz',
      4 => 'Handelskapital',
      5 => 'Zweck',
      6 => 'Zyklus, industrieller',
      7 => '﻿Handelsbilanz',
    );`

How to get the unique German words from array ignore string encoding?

Comment: The encoding of "Handelsbilanz" is identical in most encodings, including ASCII, Latin-1 and UTF-8. If two "Handelsbilanz" strings aren't identical, there's some other difference between them, like spaces or invisible characters. Encoding has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way that can make these two 'Handelsbilanz' the same, they are looking the same when I echo them.

Comment: Two  'Handelsbilanz' are different.

ASCII : Handelsbilanz   string(13) "Handelsbilanz"
UTF-8 : Handelsbilanz   string(16) "Handelsbilanz"

Comment: A string(13) and a string(16) are obviously different strings, even though there should be no difference there. You do have some invisible characters in there! Use `echo bin2hex($string)` to see its binary dump, then figure out what the unexpected characters are!

Comment: Thank you, deceze.

48616e64656c7362696c616e7a

efbbbf48616e64656c7362696c616e7a

Byte Order Mark (BOM), I will use bin2hex() to remove the BOM.